wsl false positive?
Installed wsl2 on windows and downloaded official distro of Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS from microsoft store. Virustotal shows 2 postives on ubuntu2404.exe. Ubuntu updating correctly, also hybrid-analysis shows no issues. Is there some official documentation for Ubuntu on wsl where I could compare hash? Is there other ways to be completely confident about distro?

Why ask us? Ask virustotal.  They claim there is a problem.

Fair. But is there a way to find hash or documentation?

@vengetestvengetest you'd have to ask Microsoft about where to get the hashes for the executable.  However, if you've downloaded the file from the Microsoft store itself, then chances are that's the legitimate file.  Only MS knows the hashes for all that stuff, and I don't think they have those published right now, especially since the WSL executables and such are all Windows produced, not Ubuntu produced.  Note that this is why the MS Store has an app on endpoint systems to make installation of this stuff easier and does verifications and such.

Note I'm closing this question because this isn't actually a question of Ubuntu in WSL, but of the WSL executables produced by Microsoft and outside the scope of the actual support of WSL here

Ok, thx for the answers.

Some of the lesser-known antivirus companies are notorious for false positives. It would help to know which scanners reported a positive, and what vulnerability they reported.
If hybrid-analysis came back clean, I would go ahead and install it. As an additional check though, you could try Jotti Malware Scan, which limits itself to some of the top-tier vendors.
